# Cannot mount USB CD/DVD drive

Tags: mount, usb-drive, dvd, cd-drive

I recently bought a CD/DVD drive as my new computer didn't come with one. CDs and DVDs are becoming kind of obsolete stuff, but I have tons of them.

If I put an audio CD in it -- and after a *long* time trying to identify the media -- it retrieves the track list, opens Parole media player and plays the CD. But no data disc I tried worked so far.

That's what I get when I run `wodim --devices`:

```
wodim --devices --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'HL-DT-ST' 'DVDRAM GU70N'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And that's what I get when I run `dmesg | tail`:

```
[18596.183792] usb 1-6: Product: External
[18596.183794] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Generic
[18596.183797] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 4B4D38443631313030323820
[18596.185043] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[18596.185576] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[18597.207864] scsi 4:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GU70N     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[18597.209829] sr 4:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[18597.213020] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[18597.231385] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[18597.231648] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
```

Finally, when I try to mount the device with `sudo mount /dev/sg1 /media/cdrom`

`mount: /media/cdrom: special device /dev/sg1 does not exist.`

Trying to mount /dev/sr0 outputs the same message ("... /dev/sr0 does not exist.")

Any hints? Thanks!

Fausto

Comment: Are you booting with the CD/DVD drive plugged in?

Comment: @user535733, no. Should I?

Comment: Worked for me once in the past on an unusual machine. Easy to try.